# data retrieval from genvarname-created variables

Tags: matlab

I need to pull data from the variables generated in `xvar`. The code within the loop works properly (if inefficiently), but I'm not quite sure what to do from there. As of right now, the last line of the code gives me `{ {data} 'Value3' 'Value4'...}`
What do I need to change to get `Value 3` etc to be variables instead of strings?

```
xvar={};
for meters=3:num_values
     xvar=[xvar genvarname(['Value', num2str(meters)])];
     eval([xvar{meters-2},'=str2num(char(rawdata{meters+1}))']);
end

data = [data xvar];
```

Comment: Do you get what you want using `eval(data{1})`?

Comment: The first entry in data is correct, yes, but was entered via different means. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Using variable names like `Value1`,`Value2`... is rarely a good idea. Use a cell instead. Besides this: I don't understand your code. What is the purpose of the line `xvar=[xvar genvarname(['Value', num2str(meters)])];`? The output is immediately overwritten by the next line.

Comment: @DanielR using cells made it quite a bit cleaner. I was able to remove those confusing lines of code as well. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of having Variable names like `Value1` and `Value2` I would suggest a variable `Value` which is indexed `Value{1}` and `Value{2}`. Avoid `eval` whenever possible, for the reasons to avoid `eval` view `doc eval`